# How to create template for WYSIWYG editor magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, template, wysiwyg, tinymce, editor

I have problem with template in wysiwyg editor on admin page. In **Catalog > Products > Content tab** we have wysiwyg editor, but I'm confused were I need to create templates for selecting.
[image]

[image]

***It using TinyMCE 4.9.5 Editor*** free magento extension - https://github.com/magefan/module-wysiwyg-advanced

Comment: which Magento version you are using?

Comment: I use Magento 2.3.4

Comment: Have you found the solution? I have the same problem

Comment: @adrianraczkowski nope :(